# 1/4 cup of rice not measuring to be 45g, turns out to be 30g

Tags: rice, measurements

I have used two different rice cooker measuring cups, and I know the kitchen scale is correct, but the rice packaging for various rices say 45g = 1/4 cup, but if I fill it up to 1/4 cup, the weight of the rice turns out to be 30g. What am I doing wrong? I even put a little more than 1/4 cup but still it's like 32-33g. I know different grains weight different, but I think 15g off is too much right?

Comment: If the rice package don't come with a cup use weight not "cups". How the hell they would now what cup you're using? How you would know what they used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The measuring cups that come with rice cookers are not the same size as a US cup (or indeed many other countries' cup measurements).

A rice cooker cup is 180 ml, a US cup 240ml, and in a lot of places it's 250ml. This is because rice cooker designs originate from Japan.

You're getting 30g, which is 2/3 of what you expect. For a US cup, 3/4 would be right, and for a 250 ml cup, 72%. That's probably close enough given how much variability there is in packing rice into a cup, especially as grain shapes vary.

Comment: I just did a bit of empirical testing. My rice cooker cup measures 35g for 1/4 cup. My American cup measures 45g for 1/4 cup.